# CUE sheet - last song's duration

Tags: audio, flac, cue-sheet

Question is pretty easy - how CUE file reader, like Foobar, can calculate last song duration? 
That's sample:

```
REM GENRE "Atmospheric Black Metal"
REM DATE 2011
REM DISCID 4711E907
REM COMMENT "ExactAudioCopy v1.0b3"
PERFORMER "TOBC"
TITLE "Heart Of Darkness"
FILE "TOBC - Heart Of Darkness.flac" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Through The Frozen Realm"
    PERFORMER "TOBC"
    FLAGS DCP
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "Visions"
    PERFORMER "TOBC"
    FLAGS DCP
    INDEX 00 10:00:08
    INDEX 01 10:02:08
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "Heart Of Darkness"
    PERFORMER "TOBC"
    FLAGS DCP
    INDEX 00 17:28:38
    INDEX 01 17:30:38
  TRACK 04 AUDIO
    TITLE "Nightfall"
    PERFORMER "TOBC"
    FLAGS DCP
    INDEX 00 30:24:03
    INDEX 01 30:26:03
  TRACK 05 AUDIO
    TITLE "Chains To Eternity"
    PERFORMER "TOBC"
    FLAGS DCP
    INDEX 00 35:48:47
    INDEX 01 35:50:47
  TRACK 06 AUDIO
    TITLE "Eternal Darkness"
    PERFORMER "TOBC"
    FLAGS DCP
    INDEX 00 43:26:38
    INDEX 01 43:28:38
  TRACK 07 AUDIO
    TITLE "Fade"
    PERFORMER "TOBC"
    FLAGS DCP
    INDEX 00 68:42:07
    INDEX 01 68:44:07
```

I got several .cue , and Foobar is reading them fine, but the problem is that with the last song it displays "?" inside duration field. I can't move around song neither. 
How can I fix it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ripped several CDs with EAC and found the "?" as the duration of the last track in foobar2000. I think the reason is that I put a number before the name of the .flac and .cue file to keep order. After removing the number, the duration of the last track is back.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean that you put number in filename and that was a reason? I'm guessing that this '?' issue happens when foobar can't read flac's bitrate. With bitrate it's able to calculate last song's duration based on file size.

Answer (score 2):

I am completely new to foobar2000 and don't understand when and why the programm has problems with the duration of the last track. However, so far ->Properties of the last track ->Tools and 'Reload info' always led to the correct display of the duration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I found that simply opening and then saving the .cue file caused it to work properly in Foobar. Weird stuff. I add an extra blank line at the end of file for good measure.